# Custom save button shows 'Are you sure you want to...' dialog

Tags: publish, customization

I'm looking for a way to replace the submitdiv meta box (publish box) with just one simple save button. By looking at Core I see there's a simple function returning a submit button:     get_submit_button() .

I have no problem replacing the publish metabox , showing just one simple 'save' button and making sure the post has the right status with the     wp_insert_post_data() hook. However, when I edit a post and try to save ,the 'Are you sure you want to...' dialog appears. I'm guessing a nonce of some sort is missing, but I can't figure out where.

Please note that I do **not** just want to blend out stuff with **css**. This is unsave and quite frankly (in my opinion) , unreliable.

Here's what I have so far:

```
/* Remove the default publish meta box
 *
 */
add_action( 'admin_head',  'cs_admin_meta_boxes' );
function cs_admin_meta_boxes(){
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv',  'cpt_name', 'side');
}

/* Add meta 'save' meta box
 *
 */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cs_meta_box_add' );
function cs_meta_box_add(){
    add_meta_box( 'cs-save', 'Save', 'cs_meta_box_save', 'cpt_name', 'side', 'high'       );
}


/* 'Save' meta box content
 *
 */
function cs_meta_box_save(){
    echo get_submit_button( $text = 'Save', $type = 'primary', $name = 'submit', $wrap = true, $other_attributes = NULL );

}


/**
 * Sets the post status to published
 */
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'cs_force_published' );
function cs_force_published( $post ) {

        if( in_array( $post[ 'post_type' ], array( 'cpt_name') ) ) {
            $post['post_status'] = 'publish';
        }
        return $post;

}
```

Comment: Please post your answer below as a response to this question.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** Found the solution. Trick is to disable the autosave. But take care to only do this on a non-ajax save.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
       if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false; // don't disable if it is an auto-autosave
    if ( 'POST_TYPE' == get_post_type() ){

       wp_dequeue_script( 'autosave' );    
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.